# Laravel Spark controller routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I upgraded my Laravel Spark to version 6 and now I get the error ...

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\TeamController does not exist
```

This was not a problem previously, so I took a look at the routes files in /vendor/laravel/spark-aurelius/Http and compared them with previous versions. Up till version 5, the route was ...

```
$router->get('/'.$pluralTeamString.'', 'TeamController@all');
```

In version 6, the route is ...

```
$router->get('/settings/'.Spark::teamsPrefix(), 'TeamController@all');
```

I tried altering my routes file from this ...

```
$router->get('/teams', 'TeamController@all');
```

To several configurations of \settings\TeamController but couldn't get one to work. Am I missing something here?

Here are the pertinent parts of the Team Controller code:

```
namespace Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Spark\Spark;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Repositories\TeamRepository;

class TeamController extends Controller
{
     ...
```

Comment: Can you post your TeamController  code here ?

Comment: Placed the top part of the controller in the question. Looks the same as V5

Answer (score 1):

@joshua-foxworth Very likely you are trying to create the route on web.php under the routes folder. We know web.php by default checks for controllers under `app -> Http -> Controllers` folder. You are looking for this route file here from root dir `spark/src/Http/routes.php` Hope this solves your problem.